# Using HTTPS with app engine for secure polling results from a flash swf

Tags: flash, security, actionscript, ssl, https

I have a flash swf that loads from an http server on port 80. I have set up the database and python backend to receive the poll responses on HTTPS 443 at a MYDOMAIN.appspot.com using python and app engine and have required https on app engine.

In order to use the security properly, am I required to serve the polling swf from an HTTPS server too?

I am confused as to whether both parties need to be served from HTTPS in order for that to work, and also if I served the swf from https, but it sat on an HTTP website, will that HTTPS still be secure?

My goal is to secure the polling responses and make it difficult for people to try to answer more than once.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Mixing HTTPS and HTTP traffic on a single site will result in security warnings being presented to the user. If someone browses to an HTTPS site, the entire thing needs to be served via HTTPS.